# Indexing a Pandas dataframe where the index contains open intervals

Tags: python, pandas

How would I index a dataframe that looks like this:

```
i   BDia         
0   (0.025, 0.05]    0.006726
    (0.05, 0.075]    0.006650
    (0.075, 0.1]     0.005531
    (0.1, 0.125]     0.005792
    (0.125, 0.15]    0.006576
    (0.15, 0.175]    0.000141
1   (0.025, 0.05]    0.007256
    (0.05, 0.075]    0.006929
    (0.075, 0.1]     0.006551
    (0.1, 0.125]     0.007238
    (0.125, 0.15]    0.007008
    (0.15, 0.175]    0.006658
```

where `i` and `BDia` are a multi-level index. For example how would I select all values where the open interval is `(0.025, 0.05]`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`Interval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Interval.html) and then select like `MultiIndex` with `loc` or use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
a = pd.Interval(left=0.025, right=0.05)
#or
#a = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(0.025, 0.05)])[0]
print (a)
(0.025, 0.05]

df = df.loc[:, [a]]
print (df)
i               
0  (0.025, 0.05]    0.006726
1  (0.025, 0.05]    0.007256
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

---

```
a = df.loc[:, a]
print (a)
i
0    0.006726
1    0.007256
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

---

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
a = df.loc[idx[0, a]]
print (a)
0.006726
```